# 2D Random Walk or just simple math?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, physics, expected-value, random-walk

I'm looking into a physical problem that involves the following sum:

$$r(t)=\sum_{\substack{z_l=0,1\\1\leq l \leq N}}|b_{z_1z_2\dots z_N}|^2e^{-2i\epsilon_{z_1z_2\cdots z_N}t}$$

where $\epsilon_{z_1z_2\cdots z_N}$ are random phases and $\sum |b_{z_1z_2\dots z_N}|^2=1$, where the $b$'s are normally distributed.

By trying to say something about it, one could look at it as a 2D random walk problem with fixed total lenth (sum of all step lengths). Apparently that yields

$$\langle|r(t)|^2|\rangle\propto \langle |b_{z_1z_2\cdots z_N}|^2\rangle=2^{-N}\tag{1}$$

Is it really necessary to look at it this way? Isn't it just a simple calculation involving some calculation rules of $\langle \cdot\rangle$?

For further information on the physics behind this problem, see the book from Schlosshauer on Decoherence: 978-3-540-35775-9 (p. 91).

I myself tried to do it with "simple math" although couldn't make it:

I calculated $$\mathbb{E}(|r(t)|^2)=\mathbb{E}\left(\left(\sum_{\substack{z_l=0,1\\1\leq l \leq N}}|b_{z_1z_2\dots z_N}|^2e^{-2i\epsilon_{z_1z_2\cdots z_N}t}\right)\left(\sum_{\substack{z_l=0,1\\1\leq l \leq N}}|b_{z_1z_2\dots z_N}|^2e^{2i\epsilon_{z_1z_2\cdots z_N}t}\right)\right)=\left(\left(\sum_{\substack{z_l=0,1\\1\leq l \leq N}}\mathbb{E}(|b_{z_1z_2\dots z_N}|^2)\mathbb{E}(e^{-2i\epsilon_{z_1z_2\cdots z_N}t})\right)\left(\sum_{\substack{z_l=0,1\\1\leq l \leq N}}\mathbb{E}(|b_{z_1z_2\dots z_N}|^2)\mathbb{E}(e^{2i\epsilon_{z_1z_2\cdots z_N}t})\right)\right)=2^{-N}\cdot 2^N \mathbb{E}(e^{-2i\epsilon_{z_1z_2\cdots z_N}t}) \cdot 2^{-N}\cdot 2^N \mathbb{E}(e^{2i\epsilon_{z_1z_2\cdots z_N}t})$$
with
$$\mathbb{E}(e^{-2i\epsilon_{z_1z_2\cdots z_N}t})$$ the characteristic function of a random variable $\epsilon$ with (continuous) unform distribution on $[0,2\pi]$ (where no $N$ occurs). As you can see, the factor $N$ is not in the final formula, although $(1)$ says so. Am I making a mistake?

---

This question has been cross-posted on [PSE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/712532/2d-random-walk-or-just-simple-math).

Comment: Yes you make a mistake. In going to the second line you essentially say that $E(A \cdot B) = E(A) \cdot E(B)$, the expectation value of the product of two quantities is the same as the product of the expectations. However, this is only correct if the quantities are uncorrelated, which is not the case here. Moreover, your final answer would be zero, because the expected value of a uniform phase-factor is zero, whereas the answer should obviously be positive.

Comment: "$\sum |b_{z_1z_2\dots z_N}|^2=1$, where the $b$'s are normally distributed." What does that mean? The sum should be random, no?

Comment: @zhoraster Yes. If the $\ b$s are normally distributed it's impossible for $\ \|b\|^2\ $ to have zero variance.